# Using Matlab Compiler SDK: Sharing data in same class

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I'm looking to create a .NET application which calls various matlab functions to process some data.  What I want to do is have a single class where multiple functions can access the same variables.  Below is some pseudocode of what I would like to do.  I want to call one function that sets a variable, and another function that returns the value of the variable.

```
class TestClass
{
    int x;

    public void SetX(int new_x)
    {
        x = new_x;
    }

    public int GetX()
    {
        return x;
    }

}
```

Using Matlab Compiler SDK, I know that I can call individual functions, but is there a way multiple functions will be able to interact with the same variable like the above functions?

Comment: It's quite unclear ... you can of course export export multiple functions to single .NET class with the SDK (see button "+" in library compiler ribbon under "exported functions" if you're using graphical deploy tool) ... So I don't get what's wrong ...

Comment: I understand that I can export multiple functions.  My question refers to how can each function interact with the same variable on the Matlab side.  For example, how can I have two functions that each read or write to one variable.

Comment: I'm sorry but that still unclear ... a matlab function cannot modify its arguments (they are passed as copy-on-write, unless using handle class) ... do you have some synposis for matlab setter/getter functions  ... guess what you need is to keep a reference to a MWArray on.NET side but need to figure out matlab side synopsis to be sure ...